# How to use same instance name with multiple classes

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to c# and I think I want to do this but maybe I don't and don't know it!

I have a class called SyncJob. I want to be able to create an instance to backup files from My Documents (just an example). Then I'd like to create another instance of SyncJob to backup files in another folder. So, in other words, I could have multiple instances of the same class in memory.

I'm declaring the object var first in my code so it is accessible to all the methods below it.

My question is: while using the same instance name will create a new instance in memory for the object, how can I manage these objects? Meaning, if I want to set one of the properties how do I tell the compiler which instance to apply the change to?

As I said in the beginning, maybe this is the wrong scheme for managing multiple instances of the same class...maybe there is a better way.

Here is my prototype code:

Form1.cs

```
namespace Class_Demo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BMI patient; // public declarition
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCreateInstance1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            patient = new BMI("Instance 1 Created", 11); // call overloaded with 2 arguments
            displayInstanceName(patient);
        }

        private void displayInstanceName(BMI patient)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Instance:"+patient.getName()+"\nwith Age:"+patient.getAge());
        }

        private void btnCreateInstance2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            patient = new BMI("Instance 2 Created", 22); // call overloaded with 2 arguments
            displayInstanceName(patient);
        }

        private void btnSetNameToJohn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // this is the issue: which instance is being set and how can I control that?
            // which instance of patient is being set?
            patient.setName("John");
        }

        private void btnDisplayNameJohn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // this is another issue: which instance is being displayed and how can I control that?
            // which instance of patient is being displayed?
            displayInstanceName(patient);
        }
    }
}
```

Class file:

```
namespace Class_Demo
{
    class BMI
    {
        // Member variables
        public string _newName { get; set; }
        public int _newAge { get; set; }

        // Default Constructor
        public BMI() // default constructor name must be same as class name -- no void
        {
            _newName = "";
            _newAge = 0;
        }

        // Overload constructor
        public BMI(string name, int age)
        {
            _newName = name;
            _newAge = age;
        }

        //Accessor methods/functions
        public string getName()
        {
            return _newName;
        }
        public int getAge()
        {
            return _newAge;
        }
        public void setName(string name)
        {
            _newName = name;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can have `public List<BMI> PatientList { get; set; }` instead of `BMI patient;`

if you have one `patient` you not sure which item accessing and when you assign it will replace previous one

```
    public List<BMI> PatientList { get; set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PatientList = new List<BMI>();
    }
```

with list of `BMI` you can add items like below

```
PatientList.Add(new BMI("Instance 1 Created", 11));
PatientList.Add(new BMI("Instance 2 Created", 22));
```

if you need to set name of instance 1, you can get the item by index

```
PatientList[0].setName("John");
```

Or you can find the `patient` by one of the property by loop though the `PatientList`

if you need to display the `patient` details of "John", by using LINQ

```
displayInstanceName(PatientList.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Name =="John"));
```

Comment: Yes, I think that is the solution as it makes sense as I read your suggestion.

Comment: The line public List<BMI> PatientList { get; set; } is giving me the error Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Class_Demo.BMI>' is less accessible than property 'Class_Demo.Form1.PatientList' -- I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: you need to create BMI class as public `public class BMI`

Comment: that worked, thank you. The PatientList.Add(new BMI("Instance 1 Created", 11)); is erroring with msg Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Sorry for the problem feedback but I'm sure this is the last glitch) :-)

Comment: got it...thanks a lot for your help...this works great and will now allow me to create multiple instances from the same class and easily manage them!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to manage a collection of instances, use a `List<BMI>` or similar.  The generic `List<T>` class can hold (almost) any type of object, is easy to work with, etc.  It's also a vital part of the .NET toolkit that you will use many, many times.

Also, consider rewriting your BMI class to use properties more effectively:

```
class BMI
{
    public string NewName { get; set; }
    public int NewAge { get; protected set; }

    public BMI()
        : this("", 0)
    { }

    public BMI(string name, int age)
    {
        NewName = name;
        NewAge = age;
    }
}
```

The accessor methods are not required unless you need them for interop with some other system.  Using modifiers on the `get` and `set` accessors on the properties themselves you can make public-read/private-write properties, etc.

Comment: thank you...I am new to C# so I will have to study each line in your suggestion...thanks again.